# omnet++ : self message as disposed object

Tags: omnet++

The simulation runs but in the console I have this note.

> undisposed object: (omnetpp::cMessage)
>   Mysimulation.Switch4.eth[2].queue.scheduler.IntervalTimemsg -- check
>   module destructor undisposed object: (omnetpp::cMessage)
>   Mysimulation.Switch5.eth[1].queue.scheduler.IntervalTimemsg -- check
>   module destructor

Actually It is a module that I have created using two timing messages over and over through the simulation. I read online and found that this error is  related to creating objects that is not deleted at the time it should be deleted.

```
void PriorityScheduler::initialize() {
gateCycleTimemsg = new cMessage("gateCycleTimemsg"); 
scheduleAt(baseTime , gateCycleTimemsg); 
// baseTime = 2s
}

void PriorityScheduler::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
   if (msg == gateCycleTimemsg) {

      if (currentList == (lastIntervalTime)) {  
      delete msg; 
      gateCycleTimemsg = new cMessage("gateCycleTimemsg");     
      scheduleAt( simTime() + gateCycleTime , gateCycleTimemsg); 
      ...
      IntervalTimemsg = new cMessage("IntervalTimemsg");
      scheduleAt( simTime() + Interval , IntervalTimemsg);
      }

      else if (currentList == (firstIntervalTime)) {
      gateCycleTimemsg = msg;    // same message reused
      scheduleAt(simTime() + gateCycleTime , gateCycleTimemsg); 
      //gateCycleTime = 10 seconds
      ...
      IntervalTimemsg = new cMessage("IntervalTimemsg"); 
      scheduleAt( simTime() + Interval , IntervalTimemsg); 
      // Interval = 1s
      }
  }

  else if (msg == IntervalTimemsg) {
       if (currentList == (lastIntervalTime));    
       else{
       IntervalTimemsg = msg;                 
       scheduleAt( simTime() + Interval , IntervalTimemsg);
       }
}
```

> Plugin path: /home/amr/omnetpp-5.0/samples/etc/plugins;./plugins
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'omnetpp::cRuntimeError'   what():  Object pk-56-145 is currently in
>   (omnetpp::cEventHeap)simulation.scheduled-events, it cannot be
>   deleted. If this error occurs inside omnetpp::cEventHeap, it needs to
>   be changed to call drop() before it can delete that object. If this
>   error occurs inside omnetpp::cEventHeap's destructor and pk-56-145 is
>   a class member, omnetpp::cEventHeap needs to call drop() in the
>   destructor

I created a constructor as well as destructor. I also created the function finish() after reading online for solutions. Still this didn't solve it.

I also removed each message received and created a new one while sending but It didn't change any thing.

**edit:** I edited the coding with delete msg; I added and gave an example of timings and added the below part,

BaseTime 'BT', gateCycleTime 'CT', Interval 'IT'

```
----> BT              
         <---- IT1 ----> <----- IT2 ----> .........<-------- ITx -------->    
         <------------------------------ CT ----------------------------->
```

I used the same message for BT and CT while another message for ITs as I dont know the timing of the last IT 'ITx'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating new timers (messages) but never delete the old ones. Simply deleting the message while it is processed, does not work (hence the error message).

My suggestion (without knowing anything in particular about your simulation):

1. create the timer message once in your initialization function (for example)
2. in `if (msg == gateCycleTimemsg)` --> check if the timer message is already scheduled
3. if the timer message is already scheduled, cancel the timer and reschedule it again but do not create a new one
4. if the timer is not scheduled, schedule (create) it (for the first time apparently)
5. for `else if (msg == IntervalTimemsg)` --> this is called when the timer experied (the self message was delivered), hence just reschedule the timer but do not create a new message.

You can read more about self messages (often used for timers) in the OMNeT++ manual: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:self-messages

Comment: Well I read the document and I still can't solve it.

The problem that I have two timings not one in parallel. So using `delete msg;` is deleting both if I am not mistaken. Causing 139 error code

Comment: First, deleting a message inside handleMessage without breaking from the function itself is dangerous, as other `if (msg == ...)` checks will fail since you deleted the message.

Second, two timings are just two timers, you do not delete a timer, you just cancel it if the condition of the timer changes before it is over (runs out of time). Using the same message for two timers might confuse you more than it helps. Use a separate timer message for each and every timer, create them when necessary and cancel or reschedule them when necessary.
Delete might only be necessary in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

In general, timers should not be created in the handleMessage() function to avoid the creation and destruction of objects in each call. Therefore, the initialize function should create the messages

```
void PriorityScheduler::initialize() {
    gateCycleTimemsg = new cMessage("gateCycleTimemsg");
    IntervalTimemsg = new cMessage("IntervalTimemsg");
    scheduleAt(baseTime , gateCycleTimemsg); 
}
```

and the finish function or the destructor should clean them.

```
void PriorityScheduler::finish() {
    cancelAndDelete(gateCycleTimemsg);
    cancelAndDelete(IntervalTimemsg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I mentioned already I created finish as well as destructor and constructor. The destructor and constructor setting the messages to nullptr give error 137 or 139 but `finish()` doesn't unless I already have cancelEvent() or CancelanDelete() in the code.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
IntervalTimemsg = new cMessage("IntervalTimemsg");
```

you every time create **a new instance** of `cMessage` object, and the pointer to it you write into `IntervalTimemsg`. However, you never delete an object indicated by `IntervalTimemsg`. As a consequence, when this line is executed second (and another) time:

- A new object is created in the memory
- The pointer to the previous object is lost
- The previous object still exists in the memory

Therefore `cancelAndDelete(IntervalTimemsg)` in `finish()` will only delete **the last object**.
**Proposed solution:**

1. In constructor add:

   ```
   IntervalTimemsg = nullptr;
   ```
2. Change the line:

   ```
   IntervalTimemsg = new cMessage("IntervalTimemsg");
   ```

   into:

   ```
   if (IntervalTimemsg != nullptr) {
      cancelAndDelete (IntervalTimemsg);
   }
   IntervalTimemsg = new cMessage("IntervalTimemsg");
   ```

Comment: I already have the constructor and destructor as you said.

it also worked but still I don't understand the last step,
**1** I added `cancelEvent(xxxx);` before every scheduling.        

**2** I created each message only once, one in the initial and the other in a condition where it will work only once.

what I don't get **3**
`if (msg == gateCycleTimemsg) {
gateCycleTimemsg = msg;
scheduleAt( simTime() + gateCycleTime , gateCycleTimemsg);
 scheduleAt( simTime() + Interval , IntervalTimemsg);`
already intervalTimemsg was received and later gateCycleTimemsg.

Comment: **1**) `cancelEvent()` only removes a message from the future event set, and it **does not remove any object in memory** **2**) In your code a new `cMessage` with the name `IntervalTimemsg` is created **every time** when `gateCycleTimemsg` is received, undoubtedly it is **more than once**. **3**) The line `IntervalTimemsg = msg;` is needless, because `msg` is already equals to `IntervalTimemsg`.